# Añadir minutos a fecha

Tags: php

Estoy intentando sumar +5 minutos a una fecha de la siguiente manera, pero no las suma

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$expDate = date($now, (strtotime ("+5 Minute")));
```

En cambio si traigo la fecha directamente del servidor si funciona

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$expDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (strtotime ("+5 Minute")));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Crea una instancia de la clase `DateTime()`
- Modifica la fecha y hora que tendrás como salida mediante el método `modify` el cual acepta un *string* indicando el incremento
- Finalmente a la salida dale un formato también como *string*

Código:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fechaUno = new DateTime();

echo $fechaUno->modify("+35 minute")->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

Salidas:

> Sin la modificación:

```
2020-04-01 07:53:12
```

> Con la modificación:

```
2020-04-01 08:28:28
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [función modify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php)
- [datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Esta es la respuesta más idónea. Trabajar con objetos `DateTime` y el formato usarlo únicamente si es necesario para la salida. Mi +1.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que se este respondiendo exactamente lo que pregunta el OP. El problema a resolver es como sumar minutos a la fecha en la variable `$now`. PD: el problema es que `date()` toma como primer parámetros el formato en que va a devolver la fecha, **no parsea fechas formateadas**.

Comment: @Marcos no entiendo del todo tu comentario. ¿Te refieres a que la respuesta debería ir encaminada a explicar por qué no funcionaba? En mi caso, siempre recomiendo que cuando se va a trabajar con fechas se use `DateTime` en lugar de `date`, porque siempre es mucho más flexible trabajar con objetos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, exactamente. Esta respuesta plantea una forma diferente de hacerlo, pero no responde al OP porque no le funciona su código.

Comment: @Marcos Ummm quizá quisiste decir: *no responde al OP por qué no le funciona su código* ... Con esta respuesta su código le funciona de manera diferente, pero también de manera más óptima. En la comunidad de programadores se recomienda usar `DateTime` cuando se trabaja con fechas ([ver aquí por ejemplo](https://phptherightway.com/#date_and_time)). A mi juicio, las respuestas no deben centrarse sólo en que el código funcione basándose en el estilo que OP esté implementando, si es posible se pueden sugerir mejores prácticas, como ocurre por ejemplo con el caso de la *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score -1):

Trata de hacer lo siguiente:

```
$anadir_minutos = 10;

$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $anadir_minutos . 'M'));

$expDate = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i');

echo $expDate;
```

Si lo que quieres es trabajar sobre una hora concreta tienes que modificar la variable `$now` de la siguiente manera:

```
$now = new DateTime('2020-04-01 15:00');
```

Comment: Tu respuesta no es óptima. Con `DateInterval` se crea otro objeto, con el consiguiente desprecio del método `modify` de la clase `DateTime` que sirve precisamente para modificar fechas. `DateInterval` tiene otro propósito, no hace falta usarlo para añadir `5`minutos a una fecha. Es como coger un avión para ir a hacer la compra al mercado.